# Can I use only FCM firebase without using Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I am working on React Native application with MongoDB. I need a service to send push notifications to the user whenever a certain field is updated. I don't want to use the Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore, I only need FCM service.
or is there any other service that can help me to achieve push notifications resembling FCM?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use only FCM firebase without using Firebase Database?

Yes, you can. According to the documentation of [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/push-notifications/) it is said that:

> MongoDB Realm supports integrating mobile (Android and iOS) apps with the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) service to provide push notifications. You configure and send notification messages from within the Realm console, while clients register with `Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)` for messages sent to specific topics.

Comment: Hey Nageeta. Can I help with other information?